# Override django's RelatedManager for model

Tags: django, relation

How i can override manager for relations? For example:

```
user.entry_set # django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager
```

But i need for my own manager. I try this code, but this does not work:

```
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True
```

Thanks.

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, why do you think you need a custom manager?

Comment: Why doesn't `use_for_related_fields` "work"? That's what it's *for*, so if it's not working, there's something screwed up in your code. *Always post the code.*

Comment: @ChrisPratt In reality it works only with `OneToOneField` relations ([ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14891)).

Comment: @DrTyrsa: got that backwards actually. Ticket is about default manager being used for related manager when it is *not* supposed to be. In the  OP's case where he *does* want it to be used, the ticket does not apply.

Comment: @ChrisPratt not just got, it is backwards. Read the discussion in ticket. And anyway have you tried it? Does it work? I tried. It doesn't.

Comment: I'm using it on pretty much all my custom managers and it works fine. (Django 1.3.1)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You task requires rather hacky code which will be very hard to maintain and understand (if it's even possible).

What about this?

```
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        # do anything you want

# usage
Entry.objects.by_user(user=user)
```