# Defining custom RelatedManager in django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-1.7, django-managers

I want to override related manager for a class.

I have a `Company` model. It has `state` column which can be in `ACTIVE`, `INACTIVE`, `SUSPENDED`. I am adding 2 new states called `SALES`, `CLOSED`.

Since its legacy model, just adding state can be devastating(there are very many places in code which doesn't filter by state).

So, to avoid inadvertent changes elsewhere, I decided to hide our new states for all other apps/elsewhere unless required otherwise (I'll whitelist only for our app/models)

I've overridden object manager in company.

```
class CompanyManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CompanyRelatedManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(state__in=['SALES', 'CLOSED'])

class Company(models.Model):
    _default_manager = models.Manager()
    objects = CompanyManager()
    allObjects = models.Manager()

    name = models.TextField()
    ...
    salesContact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
```

The problem is that `Company.objects.filter(blah=blah)` filters out new states. But something like `salesContact.companies.all()` doesn't.

```
In [9]: salesContact.companies
Out[9]: <django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager at 0x12157a990>
```

My question is how to override the related manager of the `salesContact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)` and the likes so that I can modify the default queryset to exclude my new state.

And, I can't override the default manager, since overriding default manager also implies that I am overriding the `db_manager` which results in un-intended consequence (db tries to insert instead of update, whole other story).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547583/override-djangos-relatedmanager-for-model/ doesn't answer my question since the answer there suggested an alternative approach specific to that problem.

Comment: I am working on it. Unfortunately I am @ django1.7, so trying your soln in a virtual env.

Comment: sorry missed the part about this being on django 1.7. But I think you should upgrade because 1.7 is no longer supported. Migrations feature alone would make the upgrade totally worth your while.

Comment: The problem with django is that companies fork and keep on adding to the fork without actually adding to django. Yes, we are working on untangling fork and upgrade

Comment: Yes that's a bit of an issue. That's why other companies build pluggable apps or subclass existing django classes.

Comment: Is this sorted out now?

Comment: Since I am @ django 1.7, it gives me no way to customize related manager. However, I managed to write my own extension of foreign key which allows me to specify custom function which can return queryset. I'll consolidate what I've did and will post here.